# How to assert/test when uninitialised memory is passed to function

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, memory-management

I have a situation where a part of my code has been found to be passed uninitialized memory at times. I am looking for a way in which I could assert when this case occurs when running with the debug-heap. This is a function that could be thrown about in places for that extra help in tracking bugs:

```
void foo( char* data, int dataBytes )
{
    assert( !hasUninitialisedData(data,dataBytes) ); //, This is what we would like
    ...
}
```

I have seen that there are tools like valgrind and as I run on windows there is DrMemory. These however run external to the application so don't find the issue when it occurs for the developer. More importantly these throw up thousands of reports for Qt and other irrelevant functions making things impossible.

I think the idea is to have a function that would search for the 0xBAADFOOD within the array but there are a whole series of potential hex values and these change per platform. These hex values may also sometimes be valid when integers are stored so not sure if there is more information that can be obtained form the debug-heap.

I am primarily interested the potential there could be a CRT function, library, visual-studio breakpoint, or other helper function for doing this sort of check. It 'feels' like there should be one somewhere already, I couldn't find it yet so if anybody has some nice solutions for this sort of situation it would be appreciated.

EDIT: I should explain better, I know the debug-heap will initialize all allocations with a value in attempt to allow detecting uninitialised data. As mentioned the data being received contains some 0xBAADFOOD values, normally memory is initialized with 0xCDCDCDCD but this is a third party library allocating the data and apparently there are multiple magic numbers hence I am interested if there is a generalized check hidden somewhere.

Comment: It's a catch 22 situation: you cannot examine the content of uninitialized memory without triggering undefined behavior, and you cannot be certain that the memory has been initialized without examining its content. One way around this is to ask that your API is passed a `struct`/`class` instead of a buffer, and keep an "is initialized" marker in your `struct`. Unfortunately, this isn't bulletproof either.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to detect uninitialized memory which causes undefined behavior. The question asked in relation to reading allocated memory that has been initialised to 0xCD is by no means undefined behavior though. I have updated the details though as this memory comes for a 3rd party library and it is partly uninitialized buffers as in every 4th integer may have not been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a function now that basically does what is intended after finding a list of magic numbers on wiki [(Magic numbers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29):

```
/** Performs a check for potentially unintiialised data
    \remarks May incorrectly report uninitialised data as it is always possible the contained data may match the magic numbers in rare circumstances so this function should be used for initial identification of uninitialised data only
*/
bool hasUninitialisedData( const char* data, size_t lenData )
{
    const unsigned int kUninitialisedMagic[] = 
    {
        0xABABABAB, // Used by Microsoft's HeapAlloc() to mark "no man's land" guard bytes after allocated heap memory
        0xABADCAFE, // A startup to this value to initialize all free memory to catch errant pointers
        0xBAADF00D, // Used by Microsoft's LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED) to mark uninitialised allocated heap memory
        0xBADCAB1E, // Error Code returned to the Microsoft eVC debugger when connection is severed to the debugger
        0xBEEFCACE, // Used by Microsoft .NET as a magic number in resource files
        0xCCCCCCCC, // Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised stack memory
        0xCDCDCDCD, // Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised heap memory
        0xDEADDEAD, // A Microsoft Windows STOP Error code used when the user manually initiates the crash.
        0xFDFDFDFD, // Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark "no man's land" guard bytes before and after allocated heap memory
        0xFEEEFEEE, // Used by Microsoft's HeapFree() to mark freed heap memory
    };
    const unsigned int kUninitialisedMagicCount = sizeof(kUninitialisedMagic)/sizeof(kUninitialisedMagic[0]);

    if ( lenData < 4 ) return assert(false=="not enough data for checks!"), false;

    for ( unsigned int i =0; i < lenData - 4; ++i ) //< we don't check the last few bytes as keep to full 4-byte/int checks for now,  this is where the -4 comes in
    {
        for ( unsigned int iMagic = 0; iMagic < kUninitialisedMagicCount; ++iMagic )
        {
            const unsigned int* ival = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(data + i);
            if ( *ival == kUninitialisedMagic[iMagic] )
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would still expect there is a Microsoft or CRT function to do similar or perform the magic number checks unless this is the only/best approach?

Answer (score 0):

The VC++ runtime, at least in debug builds, initialize all heap allocations with a certain value. It has been the same value for as long as I can remember. I can't, however, remember the actual value. You could do a quick allocation test and check.

Answer (score 0):

Debug builds of VC++ programs often set uninitialized memory to `0xCD` at startup. That's not dependable over the life of the session (once the memory's been allocated/used/deallocated the value will change), but it's a place to start.